# how to delete database row in example below?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I have a cancel button where the user can cancel on a file upload and it will display a cancel message. Now what I want also to happen is that when the user clicks on the Cancel button, it will look up for the file name which has been cancelled in the database and delete the database row. Problem is that it is not deleting the database row at all. How can I get this to happen. At the moment I am using the jpuery.ajax method which you can see in code below.

Below is form code:

```
var $fileImage = $("<form action='imageupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target' onsubmit='return imageClickHandler(this);' class='imageuploadform' >" + 

 "Image File: <input name='fileImage' type='file' class='fileImage' /></label><br/><br/><label class='imagelbl'>" + 

 "<input type='submit' name='submitImageBtn' class='sbtnimage' value='Upload' /></label>" + 

 "</p><p class='imagef1_cancel' align='center'><label>" + 

 "<input type='button' name='imageCancel' class='imageCancel' cancel_image_file_name='" + imagefilename + "' value='Cancel' /></label></form>");
```

Below is the cancel button function:

```
    $('.imagef1_cancel').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).find(".imageCancel").on("click", function(event) {

        var cancel_image_file_name = $(this).attr('cancel_image_file_name');

    jQuery.ajax("cancelimage.php?imagefilename=" + cancel_image_file_name)

    return stopImageUpload(2, cancel_image_file_name);

});
```

Finally below is the cancelimage.php script where the jquery.ajax navigates to, to supposedly  be able to delete the the database row containing the file name:

```
 <?php

...

    //I have connected to database

    $cancel_image_file_name = $_GET["imagefilename"];

            $imagecancelsql = "DELETE FROM Image 
            WHERE ImageFile = 'ImageFiles/". mysql_real_escape_string($cancel_image_file_name)."'";

        mysql_query($imagecancelsql);

        mysql_close();


    ?>
```

UPDATE:

Below is what it currently shows when I echo the delete query:

Notice: Undefined index: imagefilename in /web/stud/xxx/.../cancelimage.php on line 19
DELETE FROM Image WHERE ImageFile = 'ImageFiles/'

Below is the code of the delete function where when the Delete Button is pressed, it will navigate to the deleteimage.php script and delete the database row:

```
function stopImageUpload(success, imagefilename){

         $('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(imagefilename) + '<button type="button" class="deletefileimage" image_file_name="' + imagefilename + '">Remove</button><br/><hr/></div>'); 

$('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).find(".deletefileimage").on("click", function(event) {
    var image_file_name = $(this).attr('image_file_name');

    jQuery.ajax("deleteimage.php?imagefilename=" + image_file_name)

    $(this).parent().remove();
});

      return true;   
}
```

Below is deleteimage.php script:

```
<?php

//connected to DB

  $image_file_name = $_GET["imagefilename"];

        $imagedeletesql = "DELETE FROM Image 
        WHERE ImageFile = 'ImageFiles/". mysql_real_escape_string($image_file_name)."'";

    mysql_query($imagedeletesql);

    mysql_close();


?>
```

Below is an UPDATE of what the cancel button function now looks like:

```
function startImageUpload(imageuploadform, imagefilename){
            $('.imagef1_cancel').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).find(".imageCancel").on("click", function(event) {

var cancel_image_file_name_ = $(this).attr('css');
var cancel_image_file_name = '';
var style_array = cancel_image_file_name_.split(" ");
for(i=0;i<style_array.length;i++){
    if(style_array[i].substr(0,2) == "__"){
     cancel_image_file_name = style_array[i].slice(2,style_array[i].length-2);
}

}

    jQuery.ajax("cancelimage.php?imagefilename=" + cancel_image_file_name)

    return stopImageUpload(2, cancel_image_file_name);

});       
      return true;
}
```

I changed the button input tag to this for cancel button:

```
<input type='button' name='imageCancel' class='imageCancel __"+ imagefilename + "' value='Cancel' />
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?  Have you tried outputting the generated query, and then tried to manually execute that query?

Comment: @SurrealDreams I am getting no errors at all. I think the problem might be that it is not finding or retrieving the file name so when it searches to delete the correct row it can't find the file name but I am not sure.

Comment: Try echoing the query and see if it makes sense - then try running it manually.

Comment: When I echo the query and opened up the php script on browser, it shows the above in the Update which seems to make sense but also states that the imagefilename is undefined. When I upload and cancel the file upload and refresh the cancelimage.php script, it is displaying same thing.

Comment: Check if you're getting stuff in $_GET array. The Notice warns you about an undefined index for that array.

Comment: do you escape the filename if you insert it?

Comment: it could be in the javascript, where you are retrieving the name of the image to be deleted. Try echoing that javascript variable.

Comment: wait... Echoing? Alerting or logging I mean of course.

Comment: @11684 I did an alert(cancel_image_file_name); after clicking on the cancel button and the alert states it is undefined. So it is not retrieving the file name. Do you know how this can be fixed?

Comment: @Alfabravo I did a var_dump($imagecancelsql); and it is stating "string(59)". What does that mean? Was this what you wanted me to do to see what is in $GET array

Comment: [code]echo "<pre>"; print_r($_GET); echo "</pre>";[/code] and look out for the indexes. Check possible values for imagefilename

Comment: cancel_image_file_name is not a valid attribute. It depends on the browser what happens I think... What browser are you using? (so one could recreate it)

Comment: it might never have been set, check the source code after you added that delete form.

Comment: @11684 the problem I don't think is the attribute being valid for a browser, If you give me 5 minutes, I will post you the code where when the user clicks on a delete button, it deletes the file from the database and it uses a similar method the the cancel button function. See my update in 5 mins to see.

Comment: ah, forgot that part... That's really strange. Although I think your jQuery is better than mine you might recheck your selector for the deleteclick.

Comment: I updated code to show you what happens if delete button is clicked. When delete button is clicked, it goes to deleteimage.php page to delete db row. I tried a similar way for cancel button to delete a db row but as you already know it doesn't delete the database row

Comment: @Alfabravo I did your method and it is showing a blank array.

Comment: that means the filename never reaches the php...

Comment: can you put an console.log(cancel_image_file_name) after var cancel_image_file_name = $(this).attr('cancel_image_file_name'); and check if you are retrieving the file name?

Comment: @11684 I think you are getting something here. It could be that php isn't reached until upload is initialised but as we cancel it half way through, then it is not initialised and thus php script is not being reached. Just a theory. Is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: @Ander2 I did an alert method previously after cancel button was clicked and it stated in the alert undefined. But I will do a console log as well. Give me 5 mins.

Comment: @user1391585 if alert returns undefined, console.log will return empty or also undefined. This is the key of your problem, you are not getting the file name so the PHP receives nothing.

Comment: @Ander2 Yep what you are saying is correct. So what we need to do is to see how can we retrieve the file name. Like I said to 11684, if you look at the code which controls the delete button, everything works fine, when i try to implement a similar method for the cancel button, then the problem is that it is not retrieving the file name

Comment: @user1391585 I think that jQuery.attr() on an non standard attribute may fail. Try moving the file name into class attribute(in the form) and processing  the class attribute(in the script) to retrieve the file name.

Comment: @Ander2 Can you show me in an answer what you exactly mean so I know 100% on what I need to do to match your theory?

Comment: Could be time to move this to chat?

Comment: @user1391585 you could use data too. Just prepend your image... attribute with 'data-' and retrieve it with $(selector).data('image_file_name');. I'm not quite sure about that syntax, please correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these changes:

on form:

```
<input type='button' name='imageCancel' class='imageCancel __"+ imagefilename + "' value='Cancel' /></label></form>
```

on cancel button function:

```
var cancel_image_file_name_ = $(this).attr('class');
var cancel_image_file_name = '';
var style_array = cancel_image_file_name_.split(" ");
for(i=0;i<style_array.length;i++){
    if(style_array[i].substr(0,2) == "__"){
     cancel_image_file_name = style_array[i].slice(2,style_array[i].length);
}

}
```

Comment: When you say place this code on script, do you mean the cancelimage.php script? Just being sure?

Comment: no. I mean, cancel button function. Replace `code`var cancel_image_file_name = $(this).attr('cancel_image_file_name');`code` line with the code I suggest

Comment: I tried your method but it is stating that cancel_image_file_name is undefined and it is pointing to the line: `var style_array = cancel_image_file_name_.split(" ");` I was thinking that there must be a way with my code in being able to retrieve the file name, without needing to do the split, style and etc. If you look at the way I have created the delete button function and how that was able to retrieve the name, there must be a similar way to do this for the cancel button. I think there just needs to be a slight change somewhere I need to do

Comment: Sorry, I typed wrongly the variable name. I've edited and corrected. Pls try again.

Comment: I tried you edit but it is giving me same error on same line: `var style_array = cancel_image_file_name_.split(" ");`. I will update what current code looks like at bottom of question.

Comment: The selector I wrote was wrong( 'css'). I've edited and corrected so now it must be fine. I've also edited the slice length.